# Get value from javascript to html page without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using Javascript and jquery. Right now i am getting one value from html to javascript. And after that again i am append this value in html page.

HTML:

```
 <button data-uri="999999"  class="priceInCombo waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger red darken-1">Buy Now</button>
```

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
       $('.priceInCombo').click(function () {
            var currntTabPrice = $(this).data('uri');          
            $(".qq").text(currntTabPrice);
        });
```

After that append this value in class(qq) in same page.

```
 <div class="qq">
 </div>
```

But i want to plus some digit like 30. How to add 30 in class(qq) value.

If you  open in console then you can see.
[image]

I want to add some value after append the java script value. But i don't know how to add value after the append javascript value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that you are retriving a number (integer/float)

```
var price = parseFloat($(".qq").html());
```

after that make the sum (or anything else) and replace the value

```
price += 30M
$(".qq").html(price);
```

Comment: I want add 30 in html page. Not in JavaScript .

Comment: I want add 30 after append the value. Like <div class="qq"></div>. Add 30 in this div.

Comment: $(".qq").html("30");